# How can I open jnlp files with "lbnetx-java"?

Tags: java

What is

> libnetx-java

package and how can I use it (to open *'.jnlp'* files)??

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> What is `libnetx-java`?

From the packages page it states that [linnetx-java](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libnetx-java) is:

An open-source JNLP client

Netx is a high-quality implementation of the Java Network Launching Protocol (JNLP). It downloads code over the network for applications and applets, caches it, and runs it in a secure environment.

General Features of netx and JNLP:

- Quality: Highest quality open-source JNLP client.
- Modular: Easily add JNLP capabilities to any applications.
- Security: Run code in a sandbox or log its activities.
- Small Size: Loads from a ~130K JAR file.
- Auto-Update: No special code needed to auto-update apps.
- Fast startup: Runs code from a cache for fast starting.
- Saves Memory: Supports running apps in a shared JVM.
- No Browser: Runs apps and applets without a browser.
- Web Based: No installers needed to deploy an application

---

> how can I use it (to open '.jnlp' files)??

With a browser (firefox for instance).

In firefox preferences, select to open `.jnlp` files using javaws. You might need to install `icedtea-netx`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Rinzwind, for taking the time to reply. I saw this page while I was searching for clues. Everything works just fine without this particular package. Just wanted to know if installing this would improve anything (security, performance etc). Please reply if you have any more info. Thanks again.

Comment: what page? No link in your comment (if you mean icetea-netx; no it might not be needed since it is a "replacement" for javaws).

Comment: Sorry I meant the page with info you shared above. Icedtea-netx and everything else is installed and everything works perfectly well. I noticed this package called "libnetx-java" in the repository and just wondered if this would help to improve anything. Thanks.

Comment: Oh like that then: no!. ibnetx-java is for coders (it lets them add jnlp support to applications).

Comment: Well, I guess that answers my question :) Thanks for your time, buddy.